# PDF Generation form HTML using ITextRenderer

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I am using ITextRenderer to generate PDF from html. However I am getting following exception:

```
Error Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Could you please help me?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably caused by lack of encoding declaration in your xml file

XML file header: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>`
You should have something like this ( or other encoding type ) at the very top of your xml file.

OR

You do not escape special characters

Comment: Thanks for the response.The generated html was not as expected.We are using velocity template to dynamically generate html.The generated html had velocity markup.That was the cause.

Comment: @Maciej Cygan.. Can you please explain how to escape special characters?

Comment: @Bhaskar have a look at this link http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XML/EscapingData.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned that in which programming language you are working.
I am assuming that you are doing this in Java.
writeNextDocument() lets you render multiple X/HTML documents onto the 
same PDF.  It doesn't let you paste PDFs together.  The error comes 
from the XML parser trying to parse the PDF document as an XML 
document.  The easiest way to do what you want is to render the X/HTML 
to a PDF with FS and then use iText directly to paste them together 
(Google will turn up examples of this).

https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/wiki/FAQPDF#How_can_I_print_multiple_pages_on_to_one_PDF,_if_they_come_from_multiple_documents